# Replace *<BR> with <li>

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following text:

```
*<BR> Bullet1 *<BR>Bullet 2 *<BR>Bullet 3 *<BR>Bullet 4
```

I want to replace every `*<BR>` with `<li>` but also place a `</li>` at the end of the text (When it reaches a new `*<BR>` or can't find any)

The trick thing is that I also need a `<ul>` around all the li's to make it valid html.

I thought about using regular expressions but to honest I can't quite grasp the concept of it.

Comment: Before questionning, what have you tried?

Comment: My idea was to split the text with *, then see if the first word is <BR>, if it is then I replace it with <li>. But to honest this made it very messy and I was curious if there was any other way.

Comment: One thing to note is that I believe `</li>` can be implied rather than explicit so you don't necessarily need to place them (because opening another `<li>` automatically closes the already open one and likewise `</ul>` will automatically close the open `</li>`. I assume this is still the case in HTML 5 but I've not checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea. Read this thread for why [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-notbut). If you are sure there will be no other html markup in it, a simple split would work

```
var str = "*<BR> Bullet1 *<BR>Bullet 2 *<BR>Bullet 3 *<BR>Bullet 4";
var parts = str.split("*<BR>");
parts.shift();
var html = "<li>" + parts.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
console.log(html);
```

Comment: More on parsing HTML with regex.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Sorry I know this is not a pretty solution but the text is from an external datasource so I have to do it this way :( I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: There are other ways of doing it. Basic walking of the DOM and checking nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Quick but dirty:

```
var text = '*<BR> Bullet1 *<BR>Bullet 2 *<BR>Bullet 3 *<BR>Bullet 4';
var result = '<ul>' + text.replace(/\*<BR>/g, '</li><li>').substring(5) + '</li></ul>';
// result = "<ul><li> Bullet1 </li><li>Bullet 2 </li><li>Bullet 3 </li><li>Bullet 4</li></ul>"
```

More info about regular expression replace in javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp &
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Dirty because of W3Schools ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is the best way to do this, but here's how it could be done with regex:

```
var str = "*<BR> Bullet1 *<BR>Bullet 2 *<BR>Bullet 3 *<BR>Bullet 4";

var res = "<ul>" + str.replace(/\*<BR>[\s]?([^\*]+)/g, "<li>$1</l1>") + "</ul>";

console.log(res);
```

Output:

```
<ul><li>Bullet1 </li><li>Bullet 2 </li><li>Bullet 3 </li><li>Bullet 4</li></ul>
```

Working Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BkbrF/4/